# Issue in filling color of the polygon drawn on a Map

Tags: android, google-maps

```
private void drawPolygon(List<LocationPointsModel> locationPoints, String fencingColor) {

    mMap.clear();
    PolygonOptions rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    rectOptions.strokeColor(Color.parseColor(fencingColor));
    rectOptions.strokeWidth(2);
    String fillcolor = Constants.FILL_COLOR_GEOFENCE + fencingColor.substring(1);//creating opacity less color
    rectOptions.fillColor(Color.parseColor(fillcolor));
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    int size = locationPoints.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(locationPoints.get(i).getLat(), locationPoints.get(i).getLon());
        latList.add(latLng);
        rectOptions.add(latLng);
    }

    Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(rectOptions);
}
```

In some cases if the polygon lines intersect fill color is not properly rendered.[Polygon Fill color Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxaD3.png). Is that possible to fill polygon with following way. [Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fvrc.png).

Comment: This link might help you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial

Comment: The issue is drawing polygon when a polygon line extends over another otherwise its fine

Answer (score 2):

It looks like filling color of self intersecting polygons is not supported by Google Maps Android API.

There is a bug report in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35823225#comment15

The comment #15 posted by Google rep states

> We do not support self-intersecting polygons (either the outline or the hole intersecting)

Also the issue with intersecting polygons and filling is mentioned in the documentation. Look at the hollow polygons section

> If the hole intersects the outline of the polygon, the polygon will be rendered without any fill.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#create_a_hollow_polygon

Looks like polygon intersections and filling are not compatible in Maps Android API.